# how to send php request without waiting for response?

Tags: php, function, curl

I want to send request and run a Php code but for this I'm using `foreach` function, because of waiting for response, `foreach` works very slow and it doesn't complete the ring.
now I'm using this :

```
foreach($array as $item){ file_Get_contents("example.com/$item"); }
```

how can i solve it?!

Comment: [Promises](https://github.com/guzzle/promises) ([ReactPHP too](https://github.com/reactphp/promise)) would work, as well as [Icicle with Awaitables](https://github.com/icicleio/icicle). However, what you may be wanting is an [asynchronous message queue with a background worker](https://github.com/bernardphp/bernard). Depends on the specificity of the application, which there's not enough info in the question to make a recommendation.

Comment: Another option is to do the [`flush()` routine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php), where you opportunistically return output before the processing is complete, without killing the processing. The problem with this is that you're consuming a connection still the whole time. If you have a small number of concurrent requests and feel you can get away with that, combine that with [generators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php) to limit memory consumption.

Comment: thanks for answering <3
could you please help me with codes?! how should i  use this libraries?!

Comment: [Really?](https://cdn.meme.am/cache/instances/folder642/500x/51011642/i-can-haz-cat-i-can-haz-teh-codez.jpg) Try this blog post, it may help: https://blog.madewithlove.be/post/concurrent-http-requests/

Comment: Create a context for `file_get_contents` and specify a low timeout (1ms). You can google all of what I wrote, it's even documented at `file_get_contents` docs page. You don't have to use the right way, which is what Jared is suggesting, you can keep doing it the bad way, have it done quickly and keep adding to PHP's bad reputation for doing so.